# Can we group SSRS Fields in columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a Sql query that returns the below:

```
  Id   Name  Jan    Feb    Mar
331    John  100    23     21
442    Henry  24    55     54
```

I want to display it as per below on SSRS:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
UserDetails   Jan   Feb   Mar
    331      
   John
  Payments    100    23   21

    224
   Henry
  Payments    24     55    44
```

I have tried to manipulate the Sql but I am having issues with the grouping of the Id. Is there a way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to concatenate values together:

```
select concat(id, ' ', name, ' ', 'Payments') as userDetails,
       jan, feb, mar
from t;
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. The records should be displayed on different rows.

Comment: @avdeveloper . . . That seems like a really bad idea.  But if you need to do that, do it at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select concat(UserDetails, ' ', tt.jan, ' ', tt.feb, ' ', tt.mar)
from table t cross apply
     ( values (convert(varchar(255), id), null, null, null), 
              (name, null, null, null), 
              ('Payments', jan, feb, mat)
     ) tt(UserDetails, jan, feb, mar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave you data as it is. It's simple to do in SSRS.

Add a table control, on the details row, right click the first textbox and do "Insert Row => Inside Group After". Repeat this to add a third row.

Now just drag the fields from the dataset to the respective textboxes and finally set the remaining textbox to you static text "Payments"